# Ubuntu doesn't show Applications, can't even open a Terminal or FileExplorer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gnome

After I did two changes to my Ubuntu system today it didn't even boot any more. Let me explain further:

First thing: I want to develop my own Gnome Extensions - therefore I did a bit a research and might destroyed the gnome shell. I already used the GnomeTweak tool, but since I couldn't find a directory (according to my research) I tried: `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`.

Second: Simultaneously I was setting up Ubuntu and GitLab on my Raspberry Pi. By accident (didn't notice that I was working on my PC after a Pi reboot) I installed GitLab on my PC. Therefore I used the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl openssh-server ca-certificates tzdata perl
sudo apt-get install -y postfix
```

Then I tried to remove the installed packages by simpy using

```
sudo apt remove curl  openssh-server ca-certificates tzdata perl postfix
```

Later I noticed that my Gnome shell's icons were going crazy. Since I wasn't able to use my camera in a Zoom call I rebooted my PC and I came up to the following black screen:

```
/dev/sda6: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
```

FYI: /dev/sda6 is my /, since I am on a dual boot system. Earlier I never had problem's with dual boot and my Windows10 is still working perfectly.

Did anyone came up across similar problems and can help me?
Since my data is synced to my server there won't be a data loss - happily.

I did some research about this black screen. Apparently on some system's it had something to do with their Nvidia graphics card - can't be the problem since my laptop's graphic card isn't from Nvidia.

Comment: Did you read the output of the `apt install` command? as I bet you didn't actually install `tzdata` for example; but you did force it's removal (plus anything the has *depends* rule on it - forced with use of the -y option).  You should only use `-y` when you know the results; and it doesn't look like you did (I'd not force install of `tzdata` as it'd likely only change the package status to *manually installed* and I bet that wasn't your intention! as it allows it to be removed more easily as you removed some protections). I see no release details; only what appears to be operator error

Comment: Since it got the install instructions from GitLab's official Website I supposed that nothing can go wrong. My best guess is that I removed packages that I shouldn't remove.

Comment: My next idea would be to reinstall curl, tzdata and perl (no idea what they are for, but the other's are probably not necessary for a working system - i guess?).
I still can go into recovery mode, but don't want to make an even bigger mess.... @guiverc

Comment: You've still not provided OS & release details;  `tzdata` contains world timezone data..  I used that package only as example.  I'd be looking at your actual logs on the system to see what your commands actually did - that would provide the best fix for your *unstated* OS & release.

Comment: So I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS @guiverc

Comment: How to provide you more information? I can't even open a browser on my PC atm ...
I'm not really an expert, more a beginner to Linux

Comment: If you can help me I'd be really happy, otherwise I'll just set my system up again (: @guiverc

Comment: I would look at what you did with your removal command. The logs are `/var/log/apt/history.log`  (i'd use `view` though you've not likely got that installed so can page with `less`; ie. `less /var/log/apt/history.log`). If you can't open a GUI terminal; use a text one (ctrl+alt+F4 for example). I use `apt-cache rdepends` to view reverse-depends rules; but your use of `-y` told your system you'd evaluated the results before hand & thus accepted consequences & just to do it (don't use `-y` unless you've done your homework beforehand!).